# Need help with sorting layers on a 2D game made in Unity

Tags: unity, 2d, layers

I'm busy with my full blown project in unity, it's a 2D game as I thought this would make a good starting point.

So to the problem, I've got 3 elements in the game. The ground, an object and a beam. The ground is set to layer 2 and the object to 3. This gives the effect that the object is on top of the group which I need. Now the beam is what I'm having the problem with. I need the beam to be ontop of the object so on layer 4 for example, but I also need it to be behind the ground so layer 0 or 1.

If anyone can point me in the direction that may help or give me any tips i'd be grateful.

[image: Screen shot]

As requested I uploaded a screenshot.

So here the object(the cow) is on top of the ground layer. The beam is ontop of the object but it's also ontop of the group, I need it to be beneath the ground.

Comment: Can you show us an image or mock-up of what the result should look like? Ordinary layer ordering can't do this type of non-transitive layering, but we may be able to propose alternatives that accomplish the visual end goal.

Comment: @DMGregory Added a screenshot with description

Comment: You can place the beam on the top layer and use the ground as a mask for the beam, but the result you're asking for seems like it would look very unnatural.

Comment: @Kyy13 - I'll look up creating masks, thank you for the tip. I don't like the way it currently looks and i figured with it behind the ground it might looks like it's hitting the grass and going no further.

Comment: have you tried moving the beam up in y value, so it's in the middle (looks like it's on top) of the grass?

Comment: The beam is attached to a player controlled ship, where the player can control the altitude so the Y position does change depending on how high the player is

Comment: In that case, you could separate the ground object into 2 parts with a horizontal slice right through the grass. The beam will be in front of the top half and behind the bottom half. Layer order goes like this. background > grass_top_half > cow > beam > ground_bottom_half. You can make the slice bumpy to follow the curves of the grass.

Comment: I quite like the sound of that idea, I think visually it'll look good. I'll have to install my editing software again so i can split up the sprite but I think that'll work.

Comment: @Kyy13 convert your comment to an answer so we can give you credit, and so Asker can mark it as correct if it suites his needs.

Comment: okay, i adapted the comments into an answer :) sorry about that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the ground as a mask for the beam, but I think it will give you an unnatural looking effect.

Another option is to separate the ground sprite into 2 parts with a horizontal slice right through the grass. The beam will be in front of the top half and behind the bottom half. Layer order goes like this.

background > grass_top_half > cow > beam > ground_bottom_half.

You can also make the slice bumpy to follow the curves of the grass.